# Member value changes between successive calls of the same function

Tags: c++

I have a `CognitiveEntity` class, defined this way:

```
class CognitiveEntity : public Object
{
public:
  CognitiveEntity (FuzzyCognitiveMap fcm, SystemState s);
  ~CognitiveEntity ();

  template <typename T> void RegisterChange (std::string context, T value);

  bool operator!= (const CognitiveEntity& rhs) const;

private:
  FuzzyCognitiveMap m_fuzzyCognitiveMap;
  SystemState       m_systemState;

  std::vector <SystemState> RunFuzzyCognitiveMap ();
};
```

As shown, a `CognitiveEntity` has a `SystemState` object, which in turn has a vector of `Concept` objects (only the most relevant lines are shown):

```
class SystemState
{
public:
  SystemState ();
  ~SystemState ();

  void       AddConcept (Concept c) { m_L.push_back(c); }
  std::vector <Concept> m_L;
};
```

Inside the `CognitiveEntity::RegisterChange`, I mark a Concept as a potential cause (by calling `Concept::IsPotentialCause (bool)` which merely sets a private member with the value passed):

```
template <typename T>
void
CognitiveEntity::RegisterChange (std::string context, T value)
{
  std::string name = context.substr(context.find_last_of ("/") +1);
  int pos = m_systemState.FindConcept(name);
  if (pos > -1)
  {
    int intValue = value ? 1 : 0;
    m_systemState.m_L[pos].SetConceptValue (intValue, false);

    if (m_systemState.m_L[pos].CheckVariation ())
    {
      m_systemState.m_L[pos].IsPotentialCause (true); // Mark this concept as a potential cause

      for (int cause = 0; cause < m_systemState.GetSize (); cause++)
      {
        if ( (cause != pos) && (m_systemState.m_L[cause].MayBeCause ()))
        {
          m_fuzzyCognitiveMap.UpdateFuzzyCognitiveMapEntry (cause, pos, m_systemState);
          m_systemState.m_L[cause].IsPotentialCause (false);
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

What happens is that as soon as `RegisterChange` is called another time, the `Concept` that was marked as potential cause, is marked no more.
I tried running gdb and I am sure that that member is not set elsewhere.

I'm not sure if this little information is enough for you to give me some hints about such a behavior (I didn't want to flood the post with the code of both `SystemState` and `Concept` classes).

Regards,
Jir

Comment: You do not handle the case of multiple concepts with the same name, do you need that? If not why are you not using something like a `map`? Maybe some new `Concept` was added between the calls to `RegisterChange()`.

Comment: As Tim says below, there doesn't really seem to be enough here to go on.  You say that you are sure "the member is not set elsewhere" ... but do you mean Concept only modifies the member in IsPossibleCause or do you mean that the above code represents the ONLY calls to IsPossibleCause??

Comment: gf: I am sure there are not multiple concepts with the same name. However, I found it easier to work with `vector` containers (actually, I am new to the STL containers and I didn't really inspect other containers very much).
Also, no concept has been added between the calls.

imaginaryboy: sorry for the messy description. What I meant was that `Concept` only modifies the member in `IsPossibleCause` and also that `IsPossibleCause` is called only in that piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was a multi-threaded system, I'd say it sounds like a classic case of shared, mutable state that wasn't properly synchronized.

If you don't have a multi-threaded situation, I'd say set a watch on that variable and see what changes it.

Comment: Good advice! I found out that a copy of the object is modified, and not the original.

Comment: I can only accept it. Need 15 reputation points to vote it up, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem lied in how the code was called from within the network simulator (the code was meant to be used in the "ns-3" network simulator).

So, the problem wasn't even in the code I posted, and yet you managed to help me find the solution: thanks to the suggestions you gave me, I prepared a standalone version of the code and I watched the variable.

The problem was how I was passing the object.
Specifically, instead of passing around the object by reference (as I thought I was doing) I should have used smart pointers.

Thank you all for the great insights!
(and sorry for the mess... next time I'll be more accurate!)